# ¿ Cómo conectarme con Workbench 8.0 a mySql (dentro AWS maquina virtual EC2 ) Ubuntu server 18?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, aws, ec2, ubuntu-server

Dentro de AWS he instalado un servidor Ubuntu y una BBDD de MySql,

```
root@ip-172-31-80-186:~# ls -a
.  ..  .bash_logout  .bashrc  .cache  .gnupg  .mysql_history  .profile  .ssh  .sudo_as_admin_successful
root@ip-172-31-80-186:~# systemctl status mysql.service
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-05-03 09:15:52 UTC; 1h 1min ago
 Main PID: 2644 (mysqld)
    Tasks: 29 (limit: 1152)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─2644 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

May 03 09:15:51 ip-172-31-80-186 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
May 03 09:15:52 ip-172-31-80-186 systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
root@ip-172-31-80-186:~# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 12
Server version: 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Tengo la rules inbounds correctas, creo....

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora en con workBench intento conectarme a la instancia remota, pero no puedo. Lo configuro así,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por vuestra ayuda. No se como acceder a la base datos MySql en mi servidor Ubuntu dentro de mi maquina virtual AWS EC2.

Un saludo

Amplio gracias a la respuesta dada:

No puedo navegar por directorio de mi servidor Ubuntu dentro de AWS. Si pongo sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf   sale :

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

si pongo ls -a:

```
root@ip-172-31-80-186:~# ls -a
.  ..  .bash_logout  .bashrc  .cache  .gnupg  .mysql  .mysql_history  .profile  .ssh  .sudo_as_admin_successful
root@ip-172-31-80-186:~#
```

```
root@ip-172-31-80-186:/etc/mysql# ls
conf.d  debian-start  debian.cnf  my.cnf  my.cnf.fallback  mysql.cnf  mysql.conf.d
```

¿Cual debo editar y que debo poner?. Los he abierto y ninguno pone las lineas que me indicas.

Gracias por molestarte en responder. No se como llegar a el fichero que me indicas en la respuesta y no veo las lineas que me indicas marcadas.

Answer (score 0):

Las reglas de entrada en el grupo de seguridad de AWS ya esta hecho, estas permitiendo todo el trafico tcp de cualquier direccion IP al puerto 3306 que es el puerto por defecto de MySQL. Considera revisar tambien las reglas de salida del grupo de seguridad y permitir todo el trafico saliente de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, si es una instalacion limpia de MySQL debes permitir el acceso remoto a la instancia de base de datos desde ubicaciones direfentes a `localhost` ya que por defecto no esta permitido. Eso lo puedes lograr modificando el archivo `my.cfg` de la siguiente manera:

***Paso 1:***

Modificar el archivo de configuración de MySQL:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

busca las siguientes líneas y se descomentarán en caso de estar comentadas:

```
skip-external-locking
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

La IP que le vas a dar a bind-address será 0.0.0.0 para permitir el acceso remoto desde cualquier ubicacion.

***Paso 2:***

Reiniciar el servicio de MySQL para que apliquen los cambios

***Paso 3:***

Debes dar permisos de acceso al usuario de la base de datos. Para ello debes entrar a la consola de MySQL:

```
mysql –u root -p
```

Luego, otorgas los privilegios al usuario, en tu caso root:

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: He ampliado las preguntas con las indicaciones que me indicas. No entiendo la razón por la que dentro de AWS EC2 en el servidor Ubuntu no puedo ver las carpetas ni seguir las rutas. Pero he puesto el comando nano para editar y me ha abierto el fichero que te añado en la pregunta. Muchas gracias por ayudarme y perdona mi torpeza. Hasta ahora m había limitado a deploy en tomcat dentro de la maquina virtual alguna aplicación.no veo como acceder. Me deja instalar dentro workbenh pero no se abre el entorno grafico. ````(mysql-workbench-bin:6635): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:49:16.466: cannot open display```

Comment: Prueba mirando este archivo `sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

Answer (score 0):

Os pongo la configuracion. El usuario ubuntu debe ponerse. La ruta a AWS será la vuestra y vuestros usuarios en MySql. No olvidar que el usuario tinen que ser % para que admita entradas de cualquier sitio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]